# How to add values to a JSON column on mysql?

Tags: mysql, json

I have a MEDIUMTEXT column on my 'display_profile' table which look like this -

```
{
"artistId": null,
"memberId": "e7dbb746-a243-4247-9c27-fd184a81bd1a",
"displayName": "yoav alias",
"location": {
"value": "Rock Shilde, NY",
"publishable": true
},
"socialLinks": [
{
  "value": {
    "socialNetwork": "facebook",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/"
  },
  "publishable": true
},
{
  "value": {
    "socialNetwork": "twitter",
    "link": null
  },
  "publishable": true
},
{
  "value": {
    "socialNetwork": "google",
    "link": null
  },
  "publishable": true
},
{
  "value": {
    "socialNetwork": "soundcloud",
    "link": null
  },
  "publishable": true
}
],
"instruments": {
"value": [

],
"publishable": true
},
"favorites": {
"value": [

],
"publishable": true
},
"bio": {
"value": null,
"publishable": true
}
```

All I wanna do is insert values to "favorites" ... I searched the web

quit a lot and no luck yet. I'm basically looking for the correct mySQL

syntax to do so. Although the column is designed as a JSON it is define

as a MEDIUMTEXT. Well nevertheless I would like to add values to this column for some reason this is a tricky task .. I have tried -

```
UPDATE display_profiles JSON_INSERT(display_profile, '$.favorites', 
'red') WHERE member_id = ?
```

But I get a sql syntax exception... any ideas ?

Comment: Can I know which MySql version you are using?

Comment: How do your table look like? It is not clear what you want to do. Should this JSON be inserted into the column `display_profile`?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer the answer is no. I saw a lot of articles about inserting a JSON to a column. I want to add values to an existing JSON column.

Comment: @Jack I am using MySQL 5.6.34

Answer (score 1):

The JSON data type has been added to mysql in version 5.7.8. So it is not available in your mysql server. You need to update your server to a more recent version.

If you want to use JSON, start with changing the columns data type from MEDIUMTEXT to JSON.

Also, your query is not valid. The general form of an update query is `UPDATE table SET field = expression WHERE condition`. You are missing `SET display_profile =`.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer my 'mysql' version will take some time to update (do to different factors), if I will pursue this option I promise to update your answer as correct, thank's again.